# Regex.Replace string

Tags: regex, replace

I have a string like this:

```
"CASE WHEN TEST='rr' THEN 'aa',  CASE WHEN TEST='ee' THEN 'ff', IF (a==a) THEN BC=0 IF (B==B) THEN BF=1"
```

I had to replace THEN by string.empty but only after 'IF' but not after 'CASE' to get this result:

```
"CASE WHEN TEST='rr' THEN 'aa',  CASE WHEN TEST='ee' THEN 'ff', IF (a==a) BC=0 IF (B==B) BF=1"
```

I try to use Regex, but I'm not getting the right result. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a clear question in the slightest.

Comment: This is the first question I've seen that doesn't identify the target language, even indirectly.

Comment: I don't know if I should answer your comments or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you match for this...

```
(IF\s\([^)]+\)\s)THEN\s
```

...and replace it with a backreference to your 1st capturing group, (i.e. `\1`)?

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/bS5zQ4/1) of what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Good to hear. If it solved your problem, you can mark the answer as correct.